# ANR caused by xml layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a layout file called activity_update.xml. Here's the code :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/have_class"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/rgHaveClass"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/marginLeft"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/marginRight"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rClassNo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/no"
        android:textSize="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rClassYes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="@string/yes"
        android:textSize="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</RadioGroup>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/paddingTop"
    android:text="@string/miss_class"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/rgMissClass"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/marginLeft"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/marginRight"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rMissYes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/yes"
        android:textSize="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rMissNo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="@string/no"
        android:textSize="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</RadioGroup> </LinearLayout>
```

Here's the ActivityUpdate class :

```
public class ActivityUpdate extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_update);
}}
```

I used setContentView(R.layout.activity_update) in onCreate() and it showed an ANR on both Gingerbread and Jellybean.

I also tried changing the resource name to another layout resource and it worked okay. Also eclipse isn't showing any errors or warnings and it does compile. Could someone please point out any mistakes in my xml. Thanks a bunch. :)

Btw got the logcat output :

```
*07-14 07:33:53.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1935): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-14 07:33:53.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1935): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.wordpress.chillagestudio.attendancemanager/com.wordpress.chillagestudio.attendancemanager.ActivityUpdate}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class android.widget.RadioButton
07-14 07:33:53.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
07-14 07:33:53.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-14 07:33:53.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-14 07:33:53.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-14 07:33:53.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-14 07:33:53.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-14 07:33:53.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
07-14 07:33:53.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-14 07:33:53.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-14 07:33:53.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-14 07:33:53.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-14 07:33:53.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-14 07:33:53.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1935): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class android.widget.RadioButton
07-14 07:33:53.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
07-14 07:33:53.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
07-14 07:33:53.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
07-14 07:33:53.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
07-14 07:33:53.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
07-14 07:33:53.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
07-14 07:33:53.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
07-14 07:33:53.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
07-14 07:33:53.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
07-14 07:33:53.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
07-14 07:33:53.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
07-14 07:33:53.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at com.wordpress.chillagestudio.attendancemanager.ActivityUpdate.onCreate(ActivityUpdate.java:12)
07-14 07:33:53.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
07-14 07:33:53.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
07-14 07:33:53.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
07-14 07:33:53.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     ... 11 more
07-14 07:33:53.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1935): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-14 07:33:53.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
07-14 07:33:53.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
07-14 07:33:53.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
07-14 07:33:53.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     ... 25 more
07-14 07:33:53.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1935): Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x1
07-14 07:33:53.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:463)
07-14 07:33:53.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:787)
07-14 07:33:53.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:107)
07-14 07:33:53.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at android.widget.CompoundButton.<init>(CompoundButton.java:68)
07-14 07:33:53.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at android.widget.RadioButton.<init>(RadioButton.java:63)
07-14 07:33:53.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     at android.widget.RadioButton.<init>(RadioButton.java:59)
07-14 07:33:53.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1935):     ... 28 more*
```

Comment: please post your activity code

Comment: what your logcat output says.

Comment: This is the first time I am hearing that ANR is caused by layout.

Comment: @shree202 how can I copy just the required logcat output ?

Comment: can you post your Log cat here (just edit post and appent logcat output showing error)

Comment: i don't think it's the cause to the problem, but when you use weight for views, you'd usually want to set the height/width (depending on the orientation of the linearLayout/radioGroup) to 0 (px/dp or whatever, 0 stays 0 ). since in your case the orientation is horizontal, you should change the width of each of the children to 0px. about the ANR, do you have any other code or xml that is being used here? have you tried running Lint for suggestions on what's wrong with your code (it's the "V" button on the toolbar of eclipse)?

Comment: @androiddeveloper yes I tried Lint, and it came up with 0 warnings. Changed layout_width to 0dp (also layout_weight=1) and still an ANR.

Comment: is there any chance it's crashing because I'm running on the emulator and not a real device ? And btw, when I mentioned "it showed an ANR on both Gingerbread and Jellybean", I meant that I tried it out only on GB and JB.

Comment: @ChillAgeStudio but is there anything else that is on your app, or is it just xml ? is there code that you are running?

Comment: @androiddeveloper there are other activities, but for this particular activity and layout combo, this is all the code there is.

Comment: @ChillAgeStudio yes i see now the problem that Chandan has found. odd that ADT doesn't say anything... however, you should know that it's not perfect. plus the "?" might be the reason it didn't warn about anything ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem lies with `textSize` attribute of every `RadioButton`. It should be `textAppearance`

Change

```
android:textSize="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
```

to

```
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
```

However if you wish to set text size in terms of pixels, use `textSize` attribute something like this:

```
android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
```

where in `dimens.xml`, mention

```
<dimen name="text_size_medium">20sp</dimen>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of your RadioButton,
all have the

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

and

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

change all to

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

Hope this help.

Comment: should I delete :

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"

and replace with :
android:layout_width="0dp" ?